# Is there a better way for cross-platform newline support on Perl?

Tags: perl, newline

I've been struggling to update a few Perl scripts for full cross-platform support. This means UTF-8 text files written on a Linux, Mac or Windows must be read, parsed and interpreted correctly on any of the other platforms without knowing which platform created them.

I tried setting the `$/` record separator with disastrous results. I finally settled on using the default value for `$/`, reading the file with the Perl's default platform support, and then stripping every line using `s/[\r\n]//g`.

```
while(my $line = <$IN>) {
    $line =~ s/[\r\n]//g;
    ... do other stuff...
}
```

My question is there, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: When you say 'Mac', are you referring to data with just CR (`'\r'`, carriage return) at the end of a line, or to modern Mac data which uses just NL, like Linux does?  There are three 'common' line ending conventions (though only two of them are really prevalent): CR, CRLF or LF — `"\r"`, or `"\r\n"` or `"\n"`.

Comment: let's start at the beginning: if you do *nothing* special, what problems are you having?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: close to 0 chance that Mac here means pre OSX

Comment: @ysth: I agree, but it raises the question of why mention Mac since it is Unix-like and has NL line-endings.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should write

```
$line =~ s/[\r\n]+\z//
```

as you want the line separators to be removed only from the end of the string, and in the case of Windows files you will have *two* characters—CR LF—at the end of each line.

Secondly, you may want to take advantage of the `\R` generic line-break pattern that matches all platforms' line endings. (It actually matches CR LF or any vertical whitespace—the same as `\v`.) It has been available since version 10 of Perl 5, and you can use that like

```
$line =~ s/\R\z//
```

in place of `chomp`.

Unfortunately `$/` can't be set to a regular expression, so `$/ = '\R'` doesn't work.

An alternative is to use the [`PerlIO::eol`](https://metacpan.org/module/PerlIO::eol) module, which will translate any standard end of line sequence to whatever you specify. Most usually you will want LF endings. so

```
use PerlIO::eol;

open my $fh, '<:raw:eol(LF)', $filename or die $!;
```

will make sure that data from a file of any origin will be read with a simple LF line ending.

If your Perl code will always run on a Linux platform then there is no need for the `:raw` pseudo-layer, which is there to remove the default `:crlf` layer that is the default on Windows systems. In addition, you can then use

```
use open IN => ':eol(LF)';
```

to make that the default for all `open` calls that don't specify any Perl IO layers. That would make for a very minimum chnage to your existing code.

Although the documentation for the module says

> It is advised to pop any potential `:crlf` or encoding layers before this layer; this is usually done using a `:raw` prefix.

I have never had any problems using this *without* `:raw` on Windows systems, so if you need to run your code on multiple platforms then you may want to test this and see if it works for you.